# How to modify Elo rating to have a greater score spread?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, rating-system

### Problem:

If you go to http://www.newedenfaces.com/ down at the bottom you can see the player leaderboard. Everyone started out with a base score **1400**. There are currently over 1100 players in the database, each two being picked randomly every time you vote. As of now, the highest rating is **1572**. Furthermore **leaderboard is very volatile**. *Someone who's been in Top 10 just today is now in 70+ range*.

**I would like score to be more significant. Most people in the leaderboard are only a few ratings apart, and some have even rating.**

Sorry for the ugly and verbose code. I'll need to refactor it later.

```
eloRating: function(winnerIndex) {

    var kFactor = 16;

    if (winnerIndex == 0) {
      // A won
      var ratingA = this.collection.at(0).get('rating');
      var ratingB = this.collection.at(1).get('rating');

      var scoreA = this.collection.at(0).get('wins');
      var scoreB = this.collection.at(1).get('wins');

      var expectedA = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.pow(10, ((ratingA - ratingB) / 400)));
      var expectedB = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.pow(10, ((ratingA - ratingB) / 400)));

      var newRatingA = ratingA + (kFactor * expectedA);
      var newRatingB = ratingB - (kFactor * expectedA);

      this.collection.at(0).set('rating', Math.round(newRatingA));
      this.collection.at(1).set('rating', Math.round(newRatingB));
    } else {
      // B won
      var ratingA = this.collection.at(0).get('rating');
      var ratingB = this.collection.at(1).get('rating');

      var scoreA = this.collection.at(0).get('wins');
      var scoreB = this.collection.at(1).get('wins');

      var expectedA = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.pow(10, ((ratingB - ratingA) / 400)));
      var expectedB = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.pow(10, ((ratingB - ratingA) / 400)));

      var newRatingA = ratingA - (kFactor * expectedA);
      var newRatingB = ratingB + (kFactor * expectedA);

      this.collection.at(0).set('rating', Math.round(newRatingA));
      this.collection.at(1).set('rating', Math.round(newRatingB));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for the expected score is incorrect. For example, by your equation someone 400 points higher would have an expected score of 10/11 (0.909). This is not right, because the actual win probability is higher than this (about 0.919). Here is the real equation:

[image: ELO win probability]

where D is the number of points in a standard deviation (normally 400 points). This equation has no closed form so a table of values which are precomputed must be used.

Also, more importantly, you are not computing the adjustment correctly. The winner gets (1-*e*)**k* points. The loser loses (*e*)**k* points where *e* is the expected score for the player. So, if Player A is 400 points higher than B and wins then he gets (1-0.919)*k = 1.296 points, and the loser loses 1.296 points. In your calculation the winner is getting 14.7 points (!!!) and loser is losing 14.7 points.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post but I came up with this and it appears to be a fairly concise way of doing this.

I hope it may help someone.

```
var aElo = 1400; // player
var bElo = 1400; // opponent
var Res  = 1     // Result... 0.5 = draw, 1 = win, 0 = loss

var nElo = aElo+Math.round((32-((Math.floor(aElo/2101)+Math.floor(aElo/2401))*8)) * (Res - (1 / (1 + Math.pow(10, -(aElo - bElo) / 400)))));

alert("Players Elo was "+aElo+" but is now "+nElo);
```